# Overwriting JFileChooser java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

hello guys can someone tell me the correct code so that a confirmation message when the file is overwritten asked?

```
    {
    int index = cCont.getSelectedIndex();
    log.info("index=" + index);
    if (m_att.getEntryCount() < index)
        return;
    String fileName = getFileName(index);
    String ext = fileName.substring (fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    log.config( "Ext=" + ext);

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
    chooser.setDialogTitle(Msg.getMsg(Env.getCtx(), "AttachmentSave"));
    File f = new File(fileName);
    chooser.setSelectedFile(f);
    //  Show dialog
    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        return;
    File saveFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (saveFile == null)
        return;
    log.config("Save to " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());
    m_attachment.getEntryFile(index, saveFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All a `JFileChooser` does is return the `File` that was selected. So once you get the selected file you need to check if it exists and then prompt the user for confirmation.

So the basic code would be:

```
if (saveFile.exists())
{
     int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...);
}
```

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Option Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File", "txt"));
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);

int returnValue = chooser.showSaveDialog(mainFrame);
if (returnValue != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    return;
}

File saveFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

if (saveFile.exists()) {

    int returnVal = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainFrame,
            "Overwrite existing file " + saveFile + "?", "Overwrite warning", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    if (returnVal == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        saveFile.delete();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```